# Determine whether nonlinear boolean function is balanced or not

Tags: block-cipher

Is there any way to check that a nonlinear boolean function is balanced or not?

I can't think any other way except to check all input variables.

Comment: An N-variable boolean function$ f(x)$ is said to be balanced if $hw(f) = 2^{N−1}$

Comment: Can you explain why? And is hw meaning hamming weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$w_H(f)=\#\{x \in \{0,1\}^N:f(x)=1\}$$ denotes the Hamming weight of the truth table of the boolean function $f$ in $N$ variables, the function is balanced if and only if $w_H(f)=2^{N-1}.$

Equivalently, if we define the Walsh-Hadamard transform coefficient of $f$ as
$$
\widehat{f}(a)=\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^N} (-1)^{f(x)+a\cdot x}, \quad a\in \{0,1\}^N,
$$
then a function $f$ is balanced if and only if $\widehat{f}(0)=0.$

There are some known constructions of nonlinear boolean functions that are balanced, for example you can find some recent constructions in the paper *Construction of Balanced Boolean Functions with High Nonlinearity and Good Autocorrelation Properties* by Tang, Zhang and Tang, available on the eprint server [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/362).

Comment: @jyj did this answer your question?